# gevent.http.HTTPServer API suggests streaming, but instead buffers entire requests and responses

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, buffer, gevent

The APIs offered by `gevent.http.HTTPServer` would seem to support streaming in both directions. The request object does not offer the request body as a simple string, but instead provides an `.input_buffer` attribute that is a Python iterable, while in the other direction the data for a response can be delivered as chunks with the three calls:

```
request.send_reply_start(200, 'OK')
request.send_reply_chunk(...)  # as many times as you wish
request.send_reply_end()
```

But I must have something mis-configured, because despite this wonderfully unbuffered API, my request handler is not getting called until the *last* chunk of request POST data has finally arrived, and in the other direction I am not seeing *any* headers arrive on my client socket until the server reaches `.send_reply_end()`. Is there some switch that I have to throw or some configuration setting that I have to manipulate in order to turn off buffering and see requests and send responses as they arrive, like gevent supports with raw sockets through its `StreamServer`?

My application needs to supports single-file uploads and downloads that may be bigger than RAM, which will require this buffering to be turned off.

Here are a simple server and client written with gevent that should show you this behavior:

```
# srv.py

import gevent.http

M100 = 100 * 1024 * 1024

def main():
    print 'Serving on 8088...'
    gevent.http.HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8088), handle).serve_forever()

def handle(request):
    print 'Is request chunked?', request.chunked
    for item in request.input_buffer:
        print 'received body segment of length', len(item), 'bytes'
    request.add_output_header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    request.send_reply_start(200, 'OK')
    for i in range(5):
        print 'sending chunk', i
        request.send_reply_chunk(M100 * 'x')
    request.send_reply_end()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And:

```
# cli.py

import requests
import time

M100 = 100 * 1024 * 1024

def gen():
    for i in range(5):
        print 'sending chunk', i
        yield M100 * 'x'
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:8088/', data=gen(), stream=True)
    for block in r.iter_content(M100):
        print 'received', len(block), 'bytes from download'
```

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: I just tried this code and it worked and streamed fine. :\

Comment: Never mind, I see. The server doesn't "stream" in until the client finishes streaming. Lame.

Comment: Is this still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Requests to the server:** Looking at the source code, it looks like the server's handler function is not called until the request is complete, regardless of whether or not it is sent in a chunked fashion.  So you're out of luck there.

**Server responses:** The server response can be sent in a streaming fashion, but you need to voluntarily yield control in the handler thread for this to work (e.g. by calling `gevent.sleep()` after each chunk).

Unfortunately, `gevent` does not seem to provide a way to wait for a given chunk to finish sending before starting on the next chunk, so if you generate data faster than it can be sent you may run into memory issues.

---

Note that the above information refers to `gevent<1.0`, which uses the `libevent` library, and is not applicable to more recent versions of `gevent`.  The current version of `gevent` no longer includes an `http` module so the question is moot.